# Calculate $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ for the following:

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k3jp.png)

Here is the question:

Let $ P = \{−3,−1.5,1,2,3\} $ be a partition of $[−3,3]$.  Let $f(x) = 9 − x^2$ .  Determine values for $L(f, P)$ and $U(f, P)$

Verify that $L(f, P) ≤ \int_{-3}^{3}f(x)dx ≤ U(f, P) $ using calc-II methods for computing the integral.

I understand $(,)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i(_−_{−1})$ and $(,)=∑_{=1}^{}_(_−_{−1}) $, but I don't understand how to apply it to this.
I would really appreciate some clarification (Hopefully with explanation) :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please type out your question

Comment: LetP={−3,−1.5,1,2,3}be a partition of [−3,3].  Letf(x) = 9−x2.  Determine values forL(f, P) andU(f, P).Verify thatL(f, P)≤∫3−3f(x)dx≤U(f, P)using calc 2 methods for computing the integral.

Comment: Type out=use mathjax to render your math equations and symbols.

Comment: Have you tried finding $M_i$ and $m_i$ for this partition?